A smooth Landau-Gonek type formula
It is well known that for $n\ge 2$, under RH we have $$\sum_{0<\gamma\le T}\frac{1}{n^{\rho}}=-\frac{T\Lambda(n)}{2n\pi}+O(\log(2nT)\log\log(3n)).$$
Here, the sum is taken over non-trivial zeros $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$ with imaginary part between $1$ and $T$.
I am interested in finding a smoothed version of this, which would reduce the error term. However, I am not sure whether this is known in the literature, nor how one could prove such a result. I am not particularly familiar with smoothing, so am unsure if it is permissible to simply consider the summand of the LHS multiplied by some 'smooth weight' and try to do something with that? Either way it is unclear what to do. If anyone has any ideas that would be great!

I am a bit puzzled as I thought the above relation was actually unconditional and not depending on RH - also I think one needs some constraint on $n$ to have a meaningful formula since if $T/n << 1$ then the error is larger than the main term even when $n$ is prime (or prime power) and the main term is non trivial

@Conrad if we are considering $\sum_{0<\gamma\le T}n^{\rho}$ the result is unconditional, but for $n^{-\rho}$ we require RH. As for a constraint on $n$, let's imagine $T/n\gg 1$. Any thoughts on how we could apply smoothing/reduced error term?

Why is the result conditional? Conjugate the unconditional result with $n^{\rho}$ which doesn't change the Landau result and then rename $\bar \rho=1-\tau$ say by the roots symmetry and divide by $n$
